# Java lang object of hashmap type, how to access its data

Tags: android, parsing, hashmap

I am receiving an object from Parse Cloud which is of classtype hashmap, (checked using getClassType()), how can I access its data? there is no get(key), for this object. Any suggestions? This is using Android.

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("function", map, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(Object o, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {   }
```

I want to access id which is in the hashmap, it is shown in plaintext when 
print out : o.toString()

Comment: can you post that output string?

Comment: {Id=cus_76etS9KkqJEIig}

Comment: can you try this `((HashMap)o).get("id")`